# How to post a photo to page wall as page's admin role via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use node.js to handle Graph API, and post feed, link normally on the Facebook page wall.

But if I post a photo to page, it cannot use page role.
The photo will be posted with my Facebook user, and shown on the other side.

So, how can I post a photo to page wall with page role via Graph API

--

POST https://graph.facebook.com/#{page_id}/photos?access_token=#{access_token}

### With Parameters

```
{
    message: 'the message'
    url: 'the image url'
}
```

### OR use multipart/form-data

```
{
    message: 'the message'
    source: 'post file'
}
```

same result, help please.

The access token has manage_pages, public_stream permissions.

---

> #### Useful feed post
>
> POST https://graph.facebook.com/#{page_id}/feed?access_token=#{access_token}
>
> {
>       message: 'something interesting'
>   }
>
> this will show on page's wall as page role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to act as the Facebook Page itself, you will need to pass an access token for it. I put details on that in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16576107/183880

It's for PHP, but the basic concept should get you where you need to go.

Comment: Oh, I already pass a access_token for it with manage_pages, public_stream permission in the query string. But it just work only on feed post.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Use Facebook jssdk get page token and send it.
Thanks for your answer :)